# how can i find user details using aggregate in node js with rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
dbo.collection('user').aggregate([
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: 'usersettings',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'userId',
                    as: 'usersettings',
                    pipeline:[
                        $match=>[
                            _id=>reqUserId
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]).toArray(function (err, resSettingData) {
            if (err) { reject(err) } else { resolve(resSettingData) }
            console.log("User Data Find By Id", resSettingData)
        })
    })
```

i want to find user detail using it's id in this code

```
When we add a user's data to the user collection, the user's settings data is also added to the usersettings collection
```

But when we look at the data from its ID, we get the data from both simultaneously by passing the ID once.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error only I mean a typo mistake I will saw you how it is

```
{ $match:{"_id": ObjectId(reqUserId)} }
```

type like that after `$lookup` Object